# R2dbc transactions not working properly when using coroutines

Tags: kotlin, transactions, kotlin-coroutines, r2dbc, micronaut-data

When using micronaut-data-r2dbc with coroutines the transaction context does not seems to propagate correctly all the times, causing a NoTransactionException.

```
@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.MANDATORY)
@R2dbcRepository(dialect = Dialect.POSTGRES)
interface RecordTransactionalCoroutineRepository : CoroutineCrudRepository<Record, UUID>
```

```
@Transactional
open fun saveAllUsingCoroutines(records: Iterable<Record>): Flow<Record> = coroutineRepository.saveAll(records)
```

Here is stack trace:

```
14:37:54.217 [reactor-tcp-epoll-2] WARN  i.m.d.r.o.DefaultR2dbcRepositoryOperations - Rolling back transaction: RecordTransactionalService.saveAllUsingCoroutines on error: Expected an existing transaction, but none was found in the Reactive context. for dataSource default
io.micronaut.transaction.exceptions.NoTransactionException: Expected an existing transaction, but none was found in the Reactive context.
    at io.micronaut.data.r2dbc.operations.DefaultR2dbcRepositoryOperations.lambda$withTransaction$15(DefaultR2dbcRepositoryOperations.java:410)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDeferContextual.subscribe(FluxDeferContextual.java:49)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8660)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.reactive.PublisherAsFlow.collectImpl(ReactiveFlow.kt:94)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.reactive.PublisherAsFlow.collect(ReactiveFlow.kt:79)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.reactive.FlowSubscription.consumeFlow(ReactiveFlow.kt:275)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.reactive.FlowSubscription.flowProcessing(ReactiveFlow.kt:209)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.reactive.FlowSubscription.access$flowProcessing(ReactiveFlow.kt:187)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.reactive.FlowSubscription$createInitialContinuation$1$1.invoke(ReactiveFlow.kt:204)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.reactive.FlowSubscription$createInitialContinuation$1$1.invoke(ReactiveFlow.kt:204)
    at kotlin.coroutines.intrinsics.IntrinsicsKt__IntrinsicsJvmKt$createCoroutineUnintercepted$$inlined$createCoroutineFromSuspendFunction$IntrinsicsKt__IntrinsicsJvmKt$2.invokeSuspend(IntrinsicsJvm.kt:205)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:367)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith$default(DispatchedContinuation.kt:278)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:18)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.reactive.FlowSubscription$createInitialContinuation$$inlined$Continuation$1.resumeWith(Continuation.kt:162)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.reactive.FlowSubscription.request(ReactiveFlow.kt:267)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.request(FluxContextWrite.java:136)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$UsingWhenSubscriber.request(FluxUsingWhen.java:319)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$DeferredSubscription.set(Operators.java:1717)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$UsingWhenSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxUsingWhen.java:409)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxContextWrite.java:101)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.reactive.FlowAsPublisher.subscribe(ReactiveFlow.kt:182)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSource.subscribe(FluxSource.java:67)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8660)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$ResourceSubscriber.onNext(FluxUsingWhen.java:195)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.completePossiblyEmpty(Operators.java:2034)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoHasElements$HasElementsSubscriber.onComplete(MonoHasElements.java:93)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreElements$IgnoreElementsSubscriber.onComplete(MonoIgnoreElements.java:89)
    at io.r2dbc.postgresql.util.FluxDiscardOnCancel$FluxDiscardOnCancelSubscriber.onComplete(FluxDiscardOnCancel.java:104)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onComplete(FluxHandle.java:222)
    at io.r2dbc.postgresql.util.FluxDiscardOnCancel$FluxDiscardOnCancelSubscriber.onComplete(FluxDiscardOnCancel.java:104)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onComplete(FluxContextWrite.java:126)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BaseSink.complete(FluxCreate.java:460)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.drain(FluxCreate.java:805)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.complete(FluxCreate.java:753)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedFluxSink.drainLoop(FluxCreate.java:247)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedFluxSink.drain(FluxCreate.java:213)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedFluxSink.complete(FluxCreate.java:204)
    at io.r2dbc.postgresql.client.ReactorNettyClient$Conversation.complete(ReactorNettyClient.java:671)
    at io.r2dbc.postgresql.client.ReactorNettyClient$BackendMessageSubscriber.emit(ReactorNettyClient.java:937)
    at io.r2dbc.postgresql.client.ReactorNettyClient$BackendMessageSubscriber.onNext(ReactorNettyClient.java:813)
    at io.r2dbc.postgresql.client.ReactorNettyClient$BackendMessageSubscriber.onNext(ReactorNettyClient.java:719)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:128)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:854)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:224)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:224)
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:292)
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:401)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:411)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:113)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:336)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:800)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:499)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:397)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Here you can find some tests that replicate that behavior
https://github.com/filipenfst/micronaut-data/blob/master/doc-examples/r2dbc-example-kotlin/src/test/kotlin/example/TxTest3.kt

I also tried some different combinations of using CoroutinesCrudRepository, ReactiveStreamsCrudRepository and with the @Transsaction annotation or declarative transactions. And i couldnt see much consistency on the errors.